# h:selectonemenu is not submitting from second form p:commandButton on ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

i have two `h:forms` one form has two `h:selectonemenu`s and second form has `p:commandButton`(only)

*form_one:*

`h:selectonemenu`s(one for countries name and 2nd for cities of selected 
country) when i select one `h:selectonemenu`(of countries) and the cities will 
rendered on second `h:selectonemenu`

one `h:selectonemenu` has 3 options (e.g: 1.Pakistan , 2.China , 3.USA) and
second `h:selectonemenu` has

1. **Pakistan**

   1.1:- Karachi
    1.2:- Islamabad
    1.3:- Lahore
2. **China**

   2.1:- Herben
   2.2:- beijing
3. **USA**

   3.1:- NYC 3.2:-California

*form_two:*

`p:commandButton` which will submit selected city only

**Here is my question**
when i select any city of selected country and press `p:commandButton` it always shows me
`requiredMessage="please Select city"` can any help me for this issue?

Thanks!

```
// outside all forms
<p:messages id="globalId_messages" />


    <!--starting of form one--> 
    <!--Country select--> 
<h:selectOneMenu id="oprRoId_select" styleClass="element_spacing"
value="#{generalInformationAction.budgetOprRoBean.budgetOprRoIdBean}"
required="true" requiredMessage="Select Budget Opr Ro">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="OprRoother" itemValue="#{0}" />
<f:selectItems value=" {generalInformationAction.budgetOprRoBean.budgetOprRoMapBean}" />
<f:ajax event="change" render="#{p:component('formationId_select')}"
listener="#{generalInformationAction.getFormationsByIdOnAjax}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

    <!--City select--> 
<h:selectOneMenu id="formationId_select" styleClass="element_spacing" 
value="#{generalInformationAction.budgetFormationsBean.budgetFormationIdBean}" 
required="true" 
requiredMessage="please Select city"> 
<f:selectItem itemLabel="formation" itemValue="#{0}"/> 
<f:selectItems value="#{generalInformationAction.budgetFormationsBean.budgetFormationMapBean}" />
<f:ajax event="change" 
listener="#{generalInformationAction.getAssignedHeadOfAccountByIdOnAjax}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>



<!--starting of form two --> 



    <p:tabView id="bcrId_tabview">
     <p:tab title="Budget Cash Demands">
     <h:form id="bcr_form_4">
     <h:panelGrid id="new_demand_panelgrid">
     <h:column>
    <h:panelGrid id="new_demand_panelgrid"> <h:column>
<p:commandButton id="newDemandId_cmdbutton" value="+ New demand"
process=":#{p:component('formationId_select')}"
update=":#{p:component('globalId_messages')} :#{p:component('formationId_select')}"
action="#{budgetControlRegisterAction.getNewNumberForDemand()}" styleClass="element_spacing"/>
</h:column> </h:panelGrid> 
    // colsing tags..
```

**updated question**

Comment: Please post full xhtml and managed bean code.

Comment: full xhtml has 5 forms about (700 lines of code) should i post that ??

Comment: Why do you have so many forms? You should have one form.

Comment: Are the forms nested?

Comment: different form has different work e.g: 1.form will check (financial year is open or not, if open then it will update above form_one ok, and 4th form has some kind of demand registeration use fill all inputs and submit that demand to server)

Comment: @perissf no they are not nested forms.

Comment: @mohsinazeem You can achieve the same thing without using multiple forms.

Comment: yes you are right but why this is happening ?? do you know some thing about this ?

Comment: HAving multiple forms on same page is not recommended. You'd need to debug using Firefox Console.

Comment: `#{generalInformationAction.budgetFormationsBean.budgetFormationIdBean}`. I guess 1 of those beans is not in the right scope. Please post short versions of these beans.